# Count the number of messages in a kafka topic using Scala/Spark programming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, bigdata

The requirement is to count the number of messages in a Kafka topic using Scala or Spark programming. I am new to both the programming so i am not sure how can it be done. Can anybody help me with the code or guide me how can it be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

The methods for a given `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer` are:
`beginningOffsets(Collection<TopicPartition>)` and `endOffsets(Collection<TopicPartition>)`.

You need to remember that messages can be removed by kafka broker, that's why there is a need for beginning ones.